# check if html button is checked in php

Tags: php, html

I have a button on my form. I want to check if it's pushed or not. I tried like this:

```
<input type="button" name="btn" id="btn"  class="btn1" value="Creaza Sondaj" />

if (isset($_POST['btn']))
```

But this method is only working for submit buttons. How can I check if a button is pushed?

Comment: You cannot check anything with PHP unless it results in a HTTP request being made (such as when a form is submitted). For other interactions with the web page you will have to use JavaScript.

Comment: Button is checked  ? ? ? Sounds Good !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle pushing button with PHP, change it's type to `submit`.

Otherwise handle click event with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use $_POST i.e. make your form submit to the page with:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['btn']))
```

Otherwise, you can use JavaScript/jQuery like:

```
<input type="button" name="btn" id="btn"  class="btn1" value="Creaza Sondaj" />
<script>
$('#btn').click(function(){
  // do something
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to do is when a button is pressed, add a hidden input field to your form with javascript. That hidden field won't be displayed to the user, but once the form is submitted, your PHP will be able to read the value of that input. If the value exists, the button was pressed.

Here is a jQuery example -

```
$('#btn').on('click',function(){
  $('#form').append('<input type="hidden" name="form_data[btn]" value="btn_clicked!" />');
});
```

Here is a "raw" JavaScript example, execute this code with an `onclick` event -

```
var newInput = document.createElement('input');
newInput.innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" name="form_data[btn]" value="btn_clicked!" />';
document.getElementById('form_id').appendChild(newInput);
```

Make sure to give it a name attribute so that you'll know where to look for the values in your PHP.

Comment: and then I'll check it like this?..referring to the Jquery example:  if (isset($_POST['btn_clicked']))

Comment: @bib - no.  This is assuming that you are submitting a `form` element to your PHP. This hidden field will be sent with the rest of your form  data.

Comment: and how can I check if this is sent...I want to do like this: if the value of that hidden field is sent then do something..like when: if the submit button is pressed do that..

Comment: Are you submitting a form element?